# How to send a image with discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

```py
@client.command(past_context = True)
async def ss(ctx):
    try:
        os.remove("ss.png")
    except:
        pass
    pyautogui.screenshot("ss.png")
    now = datetime.now()
    current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    file = File(filename="ss.png")
    await ctx.send(file=file)
```

I'm trying to make a discord bot that send a screenshot when .ss is sent in the server i'm useing python 3.8.2 does anyone know a way as i can't find a way anywhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
with open(my_filename, "rb") as fh:
    f = discord.File(fh, filename=my_filename)
await ctx.send(file=f)
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer ill try it and if it works ill make it the answer